# Regular Expression Tester says expression works but preg_match fails

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to extract the em tag from a string. On http://www.phpliveregex.com/ my regular expression works but in my code it returns a 0(no match found).

```
$regex = "/<em class=\"correct_response\".*\/em>/";
echo preg_match($regex, $string);
/* sample values for the data in $string are 

    toggle('clue_J_1_1', 'clue_J_1_1_stuck', '<em class="correct_response">3M</em><br /><br /> <table width="100%"><tr><td class="right">Ashok</td></tr></table>')
    toggle('clue_J_2_2', 'clue_J_2_2_stuck', '<em class="correct_response">Confucius</em><br /><br /><table width="100%"><tr><td class="right">Ashok</td></tr></table>')

*/
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your backslash that is escaping the forward slash in `/em>` since you are delimiting your string with double quotes.

```
$regex = "/<em class=\"correct_response\".*\\/em>/";
```

This is only an issue because your string is using double quotes. The following, using single quotes, should also work and requires less characters:

```
$regex = '/<em class="correct_response".*\/em>/';
```

If you don't want to worry about having to escape your forward slash, you can use other [delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) like `#`:

```
$regex = '#<em class="correct_response".*/em>#';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct regular expression! I just tested to confirm as well.

What you are doing wrong is the way you are using the preg_match function.

Read the PHP Manual.

Here is the FULLY TESTED CODE, just copy-paste it and try it in a blank php file:

```
<?php
$regex = "/<em class=\"correct_response\".*\/em>/";
$string = "toggle('clue_J_1_1', 'clue_J_1_1_stuck', '<em class=\"correct_response\">3M</em><br /><br /> <table width=\"100%\"><tr><td class=\"right\">Ashok</td></tr></table>')";
preg_match($regex,$string,$matches);
echo $matches[0];
?>
```